# what button is clicked in my table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, socket.io

I have a strange problem... I think.

I have the following code:
In the `<body>`:

```
<!-- headers, includes and other "plain" html... -->
<div class="col-sm-4"> <!-- Second column -->
    World!
    <br>
    <p id="testerP"></p>
    <script>
        var temptext = '';
        for (var i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++){
            temptext += '<button name="deleted" value=' + i + ' class="btn btn_sm btn-danger deletes" role="button">DEL</button><br>'
            temptext += '<br>';
            temptext += '<br>';
        }
        document.getElementById("testerP").innerHTML = temptext;
    </script>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4"> <!-- Third column -->
    <h2>Robot Job Queue</h2>
    <table  id="queueAll" class="table table-striped table-responsive">
        <thead><tr><th>Id</th><th>Type</th><th>Delete</th><th>Priority</th></tr></thead>
        <tbody id="tbod">
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

In the script section after `</body>`

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var socket = io();

    // When the client receives a "queue" from the server
    socket.on('queue', function(msg){
        var html = ''; 
        var tmp = '';
        html += '';
        temptext = '';

        if(msg.length == 0){$("#queueAll").hide();}
        else{$("#queueAll").show();}
        for (var i = 0 ; i < msg.length && i<5 ; i++){
            html += '<tr name="queueRow">'
            html += '<td>' + msg[i]['id'] + ' </td>'
            html += '<td>' + msg[i]['type'] + '</td>'
            tmp = '<button name="deleted" value=' + msg[i]['id'] + ' class="btn btn_sm btn-danger deletes" role="button">DEL</button>';
            html += '<td>' + tmp + '</td>'
            html += '<td>' + msg[i]['priority'] + '</td>'
            html += '</tr>'
        }
        document.getElementById("tbod").innerHTML = html;
    });

    //Submitting deleteJob
    $('.deletes').on('click',function(e){
        console.log(e.target.value);
        var dataReturn = {jobType:e.target.value};
        socket.emit("delete job",dataReturn);
    });
});
</script>
```

The problem is:
The first for loop (the one inside `<body>` with id=testerP) runs as expected. I get the button value on both server and client side.
But, when I click the buttons inside the table I get no reaction what so ever?!?!

I can get the "testerP" buttons with the

```
$('button[name="deleted"]').on('click',function(){...

$('.deletes').on('click',function(){...
```

and

```
$('button').on('click',function(){...
```

But the table buttons react to nothing!

Why not (wheeping slightly)???

Project info:

- Node.js

  express

  socket.io

  Bootstrap

  jQuery

  My first web project with anything except plain html...

Comment: ​$(document).on('click', 'button[name="deleted"]', function(event) {}); try to use as like this.

Comment: @Prageeth wrote the comment I wanted to write. The problem is that you are trying to get the buttons before it exists (if you will add console.log($('.deletes')) where your comment is, it would output "undefined")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elements that were added dynamically to the DOM, in your case the for loop which generates the delete Buttons need to be addressed with

```
$(document).on('click', '.deletes', function() { 
    // your delete logic
});
```

Comment: This was it... it all seems so obvious now :)

Answer (score 2):

problem may be Not wrapping your code inside of DOM ready.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(document).on('click', 'button[name="deleted"]', function(event) {});

​$(document).on('click', '.deletes', function(event) {});
});
```